# Removing a particular line from shell output

Tags: bash, grep

Trying to get the Debian version number into a variable, I encountered a problem filtering it through grep.

If I do lsb_release:

```
~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.1 (wheezy)
Release:        7.1
Codename:       wheezy
```

To get just the line containing the description, I tried:

```
# lsb_release -a | grep -i 'Description'
No LSB modules are available.
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.1 (wheezy)
```

However, I still get the line "No LSB modules are available."

I tried specifically excluding it with:

```
# lsb_release -a | grep -v 'LSB' | grep -i 'Description'
No LSB modules are available.
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.1 (wheezy)
```

I still get the line containing the string "LSB". Why is this happening? How can I get the desired line alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the undesired line is being output to *stderr*, not *stdout*.  If you don't want it, redirect it to `/dev/null`.  Try:

```
lsb_release -a 2>/dev/null | grep -i 'Description'
```

Answer (score 2):

Pipe stderr to stdout, and use `cut`:

```
debian_version=$(lsb_release -a 2>&1 | grep  'Description' | cut -f2)
```

Or throw away the error messages at all:

```
debian_version=$(lsb_release -a 2>/dev/null | grep  'Description' | cut -f2)
```